# jQuery Knob dial, how to change its value on hover?

Tags: jquery, onhover

I use this plugin [Knob Jquery](http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/). I want to change dial's value on hover. Is it possible? I looked into the plugin's documentation, but didn't find anything useful to solve my problem.

```
<input disabled class="knob" data-width="120" data-displayPrevious=true data-thickness=".3" value="65">
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/almostemp/HUm3q/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change line 341 of the plugin code to also capture "mousemove", as per the second line here:

```
                c.bind(
                                "mousedown touchstart mousemove"
                                ,function (e) {
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                    k.startDrag(e);
                                }
                      )
```

However I feel that this makes the plugin very user un-friendly.

BTW this would be a lot easier if the plugin was actually a jQuery UI widget, because they support methods for altering state on the fly.  Or it could provide its own method of altering state, but it doesn't seem to.

Comment: One more question) How to make it work with this version of the plugin https://raw.github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob/master/js/jquery.knob.js

Comment: Line 319 it mentions `mousedown`, you want to extend this to include `mousemove` as well.

Comment: Extending to mousemove changes the dial_value on mouseover but continues to change even after mouseout... any help on how can we avoid that? :/

Answer (score 1):

use like below

```
$('.knob').hover(function(){place your code here});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//this is for change color, I think is same for change of value    
jQuery('.knob').on(
        {

            mouseenter: function()
            {
                $(this)
                    .trigger(
                    'configure',
                    {

                        "fgColor":"#87CEEB"

                    }
                );
            },
            mouseleave: function()
            {
                var bg_color = jQuery(this).attr('data-fgcolor');
                $(this)
                    .trigger(
                    'configure',
                    {

                        "fgColor":"#87CEEB"

                    }
                );
            }
        });
```